# react-native-navigation no funciona cuando dentengo el sever

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React-native-navigation funciona perfectamente mientras este corriendo el servidor `react-native run-android` despues de haber detenido la ejecución, la aplicación no navega entre las pantallas y cierra la aplicación.

versiones

> "react-native": "0.55.0"
>
> "react-native-navigation": ^2.3.1

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: Buen si notas lo que preguntas no es pregunta, si bien estas hablando de que solo te funciona con el server activo, es precisamente por ello, porque el server ejecuta la app para su debug en los dispositivos, mas no la mantiene en uso hasta que compiles e instales el apk, debes compilar si quieres que se mantenga la app en el dispositivo así como Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Eso ocurre porque el server es el encargado de ejecutar tu aplicación, al matar el server estas matando la aplicacion

Answer (score 1):

Cuando corres la aplicacion con react-native run-(os) la es el servidor quien procesa la aplicacion desde un puerto en tu computadora, para que corra sin el servidor tienes que hacer un build:producion y no build:debug